# How to check Eamil is available or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to check this email already register or not. I want to check When user enter email in email text box during registration at that time if email is already register by other user then message will be display.
**Aspx code**

```
protected void txtEmail_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand  cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(Email) as Email from tblUsers where Email='"+txtEmail+"'",con);
       SqlDataReader dr;
       dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
       while (dr.Read())
       {
           string iEmail = dr["Email"].ToString();

           if (iEmail == "0")
           {
               Label1.Visible = true;
               Label1.Text = "This email already registered..";
           }

       }


    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what?

Comment: So what is the error you are facing?

Comment: use this code in the leave event for that textbox, else your going to continuously query the database as each letter is typed into the textbox

Comment: I think he want to do the check,while users types in ..like Jquery Change event ..Or something

Comment: I don't get any kind of error till the error message not display.

Comment: At the moment it's not very clear what your problem is because you haven't specified one. Also it'll be worth nothing that you should use parameterized queries

Comment: So are you saying that you don't get an error but it's not correctly displaying that an email is already registered when you know it is?

Answer (score 1):

There is something to do for gain performance to this query,

First: Count query returns only A "CELL" Not row or rows. So you can use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` for this query but you should cast it to an integer like `int mailCount =  (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` 
then you can compare mailCount with 0, if equal, the mail is not registered yet.

Second: Instead of

> ```
> SqlCommand  cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(Email) as Email from tblUsers where Email='"+txtEmail+"'",con);
>        SqlDataReader dr;
> ```

this, you should use

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(Email) as Email from tblUsers WHERE Email = @Email", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email",txtEmail.Text.Trim());
```

And I think your problem is "txtEmail", you should use `txtEmail.Text.Trim()`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable `AutoPostBack="true"` for that textbox like this:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Hope this will Help?